# dotnet publish command is not creating zip file for C# library

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.0, coreclr

In visual studio solution I have single `.net core 2.0` library project. And to the publish the library i am using `dotnet publish -c release` command

[image]

however its not zipping the publish folder. I have read the [issue 6598](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6598) and use the suggested approach using `dotnet build` command as below

`dotnet build ApiRouting.sln /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="C:\temp\Routing\package" /p:OutDir="C:\temp\Routing\out" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="C:\temp\Routing\package\package.zip"`

`[image]

but that did not work either.

My project is `aws lambda` project which is C# library project not asp.net web project so i tried removing `/p:WebPublishMethod=Package` option but that did not work either.

**Questions**
1>What parameters i need to pass to `publish` command so that it would create zip file of publish folder.
2>In linked `issue 6598` why its suggested to use `build` command instead of `publish` when build command only builds the project?

*(on side note i can use `aws tools for visual studio` and use `Publish to AWS Lambda` and it creates zip file and deploys it to AWS directly from visual studio. However, we are using Jenkins for CI so i want use `dotnet` cli to create zip file so jenkins can execute that command and create zip file.)*

Comment: This is probably configuration related since I couldn't reproduce issue. The dotnet build command working just fine for me with zip files and deployment scripts

Answer (score 2):

i found it. These 2 links helped me 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-dotnet-how-to-create-deployment-package.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-dotnet-coreclr-deployment-package.html

first installed Amazon.Lambda.Tools

`dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools`

and then to package and deploy

`dotnet lambda deploy-function apirouting –-function-role myrole --profile lambdadep --profile-location C:\test\testawsprofile`